# I have some problem with clean method in Django

Tags: django

Here is

my form.py

```
class DepartamentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
   class Meta:
      model = Department
      fields = ['name','company','city', 'special_id','active']
    
      def clean_code(self):
        code = self.cleaned_data.get('special_id')
        qm = Department.objects.filter(special_id=code)
        if qm.exists():
           raise forms.ValidationError("Email jest już używany!!" )
           return code
```

my view.py

```
def dictionary_department_add(request):
    
    current_user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
      form = DepartamentForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        x_form = form.save(commit=False)
        x_form.date_add = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        x_form.user_add = current_user.username
        x_form.save()
        return redirect('/dictionaries/dictionary_department/')
       else:
          return render(request, 'add_department.html',{form': form})
    else:
       form = DepartamentForm()
       return render(request, 'add_department.html', {'form': form})
```

If I try to add a new position department using this code, the error isn't showed, and submit works for some reason.

I want that before submit form, method check if field special_id exists in database, and if exists than show message in form and stop submit

Comment: What is the problem?

As I don't see any problem.

Comment: I want that before submit form, method check if field special_id exists in database, and if exists than show message in form and stop submit

Comment: Ok. Have added problem statement in the post.